# How do you customize Tkinter buttons

Tags: python, image, button, tkinter

there is a simple code to use an image as button, but this doesn't really do what I want...

CODE:

```
from Tkinter import *
window = Tk()

btn = Button(window)
pic = PhotoImage(file="submit.png")

btn.config(image = pic)
btn.pack()

window.configure(background = "#29746f")
window.geometry("{}x{}".format(150,100))

mainloop()
```

have a look on these screenshots please:

EXEPTATION:
 [what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joYIc.png)

REALITY: 
[what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUJaD.png)

So, how to make my image transparent and how to remove the rectangle border from my button ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set border width to 0 to remove that rectangle "border".

```
btn = Button(window, borderwidth= 0)
```

It will do the job.

To remove the background, you can use software like GIMP (Free and open source) or Photoshop.

However you will. not be able to remove the button background because *tkinter does not support transparency* best practice for customized button is to make them rectangular

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer with a clarification. Note the OP still has an option to create their own button if they want to use canvas for everything.

Comment: Is there really no way to make the image transparent?

Comment: @Krob Ow: Not using tkinter buttons. Shivam Pandya is correct about this. However there is some interesting workaround using canvas but it is a bit complicated.